# In Node.js, how to read a file, append a string at a specified line or delete a string from a certain line?

Tags: node.js

I need to open an existing JavaScript file, check if this string exists:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

If it doesn't, then append it at the top with the rest of `require()` lines.

In another case, I need to check if that string exists, and if it does, I would like to remove just that line.

I have looked at `fs.readFile`, `fs.writeFile`, `fs.open` but I don't think it is capable of doing what I need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simplified script:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var search = "var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;";


function append (line) { 
  line = line || 0;

  var body = fs.readFileSync('example.js').toString();

  if (body.indexOf(search) < 0 ) {

    body = body.split('\n');
    body.splice(line + 1,0,search);
    body = body.filter(function(str){ return str; }); // remove empty lines
    var output = body.join('\n');
    fs.writeFileSync('example.js', output);
  }
}


function remove () {

  var body = fs.readFileSync('example.js').toString();
  var idx = body.indexOf(search);

  if (idx >= 0 ) {
    var output = body.substr(0, idx) + body.substr(idx + search.length);
    fs.writeFileSync('example.js', output);
  }

}
```

Comment: This appends a string at the beginning of the file, how can I append a string at specific line?

Comment: @TwilightPonyInc. I updated the append function with a line argument